# Specified cast is not valid erro for crystal report parameter

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am building a desktop application using C#, .NET Framework 4.0.
I am trying to pass parameter from my C# form to my crystal report 10.0, but it doesn't work and it throws this error:

> Specified cast is not valid.

Here are my code to pass parameter:

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
cryRpt.Load(@"Report\food.rpt");

ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions ;
ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition ;
ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxX1.Text);
crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["foodID"];
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

crParameterValues.Clear();
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

this.axCrystalActiveXReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
this.axCrystalActiveXReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: what is the value of `textBoxX1.Text` ?

Comment: the value of textBoxX1.Text is for id that's mean int

Comment: are you sure? Is there *always* a string in `textBoxX1.Text` that can be translated into an `int`?

Comment: Yes, it is always a string which is converted to int

Comment: I suppose that error stacktrace includes the line that is causing the error... please post it!

Comment: @stevenH. Can you post a solution if u got it?